# is extern the only way to write a declaration that is not also a definition?

Tags: c

Is that sane to conclude that the only type of variable declaration is "extern declaration" ?

It's known that the following code **define** (not **declare**) `x`, because it allocate memory for variable `x` (KR chapter 4). Typically though, we would normally just say that we are declaring `x` (but not initializing it).

```
int x; // <-- definition NOT declaration
```

The only declaration example I can find is to use with the keyword `extern`:

```
extern int x;
extern int a[];
```

Is there any other variable declaration situation apart from **extern declaration**?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your question.  But there is also a `static` declaration.

Comment: `int x;` is a declaration.  (All definitions are declarations).  Maybe you mean to ask "Is `extern` the only way to write a declaration that is not also a definition?", or something.

Comment: @M.M yes that's exactly what my Q is - let me rephrase the title based on your cmmt, thanks

Comment: Funktions can be declared with internal linkage (using the static keyword). You don't have to use the external keyword, but a function declaration will then still have external linkage. You can declare functions with lokal scope (inside a block), but still external linkage.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider the question was about variables - but thanks for the info about functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definition is a declaration with storage. From standard:

> **6.7 Declarations 3/** A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers.
> A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier
> that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body;119)
>
> — for an enumeration constant, is the (only) declaration of
> the identifier;
>
> — for a typedef name, is the first (or only)
> declaration of the identifier.

Then a function prototype is a declaration, which may not be qualified `extern` if used for a forward declaration. A

For more details, read the standard, section 6.7.

Comment: My question is specifically about variable declaration.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not answer the question. The question was `Is 'extern' declaration the only way to declare (instead of define) a variable?`.

Comment: So you agree with the statement that "extern declaration" is the only way to declare a variable?

Comment: Yes, but I will not say it like that, I would prefer "extern" is the only way to declare without defining.

Comment: How about function formal parameters - They are not defined in a function definition - only declared.

Comment: Their storage is defined, no?

Answer (score -2):

extern is used , mostly for functions when the function exists in another file , either sourcecode or an object library.

auto is used for stack variables, but since it is the default few people wite it explicitly.

static is for static variables, kept even when a function exits. auto variables are lost when a function exits, so static variables are often used for total counts, user settings, settings of state, which may change, but are used throughout the whole time the program is running.

Comment: `extern` is used for pretty much any global variable.  Example:  `errno`, declared `extern` in `<errno.h>`.